# Working with windows in Gtk2-Perl

Tags: perl, gtk

I am working on a Gtk2-Perl project, where I have to create a GUI. Now I have to do one thing, that whenever the user selects 'Single' Radio button, or the 'Multiple' Radio button, either a seperate screen should come up, or the content of the same window should change.

Ex: when user selects Single: He should be having 4 buttons, But when he selects Multiple: he should be having 10 buttons, and some more widgets.

Can someone help me in creating a pop up window, which will contain respective widgets, on selection of appropriate radio button. Or any help regarding, callbacks where we can add buttons and widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at these tutorials for a starting point.

http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/gtk2-perl-tut/

http://soliton.ae.gatech.edu/people/jcraig/classes/ae6382/perl/gtkperl-tutorial/html/index.html